# Getting "Javac is not recognised as internal or external command, operable program or patch file" while running Java class on command line

Tags: java, command-line

I have also defined the "set path" variable as the location of bin under jdk but it still throws the error

Comment: can you share your `$PATH` with us?

Comment: Did you instrall a JDK or  JRE?

Comment: check your $JAVA_HOME or $PATH there should be ../jdk/bin folder should be there

Comment: @Mureinik C:\>set path=%path%;"c:Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin"

Answer (score 2):

For **Windows 10**

First you need to set path of your JDK bin location as System Variables Path in **Environment Variables**. Close and reopen the **Command Prompt** window and Proceed...

**Process of setting the JDK path in Environment Variables**

1. Open **Environment Variables**.
2. Select **Path** Variable and click on **Edit** button in **System Variables**.
3. Click on **New** button in **Edit environment variable**.
4. Paste the location of JDK bin e.g. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin and click on **OK** button.
5. Now click on **OK** button in in **Environment Variables**.
6. Close the **Command Prompt** (if any opened).
7. Now open new **Command Prompt** and proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your Java home path and java bin path.